# The updated @api value is not getting reflected in the child component in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am having problem in dynamically getting the value in my child Lightning Web Component
I have a Parent Component and Child Component. I am passing the @api value as follows :

Parent.html

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="isFieldChecked" value={isfieldchecked} onchange={handleValueChange}>
 <c-child 
    isvaluechecked={isfieldchecked}
 ></c-child>
</lightning-input>
```

Parent.js

```
isfieldchecked = false;

handleValueChange(event) {
   this.isfieldchecked = event.target.checked; //value onchange is not getting reflected in child component
}
```

child.html

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" label="isChecked" value={isfieldchecked} onchange={handlecheckboxchanged}></lightning-input>
```

child.js

```
@api isvaluechecked;
connectedCallback() {
   console.log('isValueChanged::' + this.isvaluechecked);
}
    handlecheckboxchanged() {
        if(this.isvaluechecked) { 
console.log('isValueChanged::' + this.isvaluechecked); //cannot see the value updated when updated on parent
    //perform some operations
        }
    }
```

In the above scenario, when I check/uncheck the checkbox in the parent component, I dont see it changed in the child component where I am invoking the onchange method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the great help of @sfdcfox & @Phil W comments on the answer provided by @sfdcfox, here I have summarised an answer.

Key learning points:

1. onchange event on **child** is only triggered if you are clicking the checkbox **of the child component**. Although you are passing in the value from the parent, the value change in parent does not trigger the onchange handler function in the child.

To work with this, what you can do is using a getter/setter and call/perform your onchange method in the setter, because the setter will run each time there's a new value being passed.

Child.Js

```
_isvaluechecked;
@api 
set isvaluechecked(val){
    console.log('hi'); // just to check to see if setter is called.
    this._isvaluechecked = val;
    this.handlecheckboxchanged();
}

get isvaluechecked(){
    return this._isvaluechecked;
}

handlecheckboxchanged() {
    if(this.isvaluechecked) { 
        console.log('isValueChanged::' + this.isvaluechecked);
    }
}
```

Once again, I would like to thank @sfdcfox and @Phil W, for their help. As these really helped me gained a good understanding as well! :)
Credits: @sfdcfox and @Phil W.

Comment: Why do we need _isvaluechecked ?

Comment: It’s just a variable, to aid the usage of getter/setter. When you receive a value from the setter, where would you save the value? So we create a new variable and save is there. Since this new variable holds the value, that is passed in; in the getter method we return this value. Of course you can name the variable to whatever you want, such as #value also. So when the parent pass in the isvaluechecked value, setter method is called, we assign the value to _isvaluechecked. Then in the child component wherever isvaluechecked variable is used, the getter method will be called to return the value

Answer (score 4):

`@api` makes a property read-only. The parent component must not use `@api` for a property it intends to change.

```
@api isfieldchecked = false;
```

should be:

```
isfieldchecked = false;
```

Comment: I tried with this as well and it did not work so I went ahead and changed it to @api since it is publicly available.

Comment: This answer is incomplete if you consider *output* properties for use in flows. These must be `@api` setter/getter properties, allowing the property to be updated by the component it belongs to so that the update can then be communicated back to the flow.

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't expect my vote to immediately close the question! I was expecting a "Does this answer your question" since that's always been the behaviour I've seen so far.)

Comment: @PhilW This question is not about the flow, rather it is about passing the value from parent to child component. Hence it is not a duplicate question

Comment: You have an API property at the parent level, as well as at the child level. Why? Your code is confusing. Since you had an API property you want to write to at the parent level, I assumed you wanted that to travel back to a caller - and assumed flow, since that's the only case I'm aware of that warrants a writable API property...

Comment: The child should raise a custom event to communicate a change in state back to the parent, and the parent should simply handle the event and hold this updated state in a non-api property as per sfdcfox's answer.

Comment: As suggested I removed the @api property from the parent component variable, but it is still not working.

Comment: I am trying to get the change in parent component to the child component and not the other way around

Comment: So sfdcfox's suggestion looks right to me and there must be something else, not in the question, causing the trouble.

Comment: @SFDCLearner Note that a checkbox uses the `checked` property--if you're expecting the child checkbox to check, use `<lightning-input checked={isvaluechecked}` ...

Comment: @sfdcfox correct, but I don't get the updated value itself at first place in isvaluechecked, In parent : handleValueChange function will check/uncheck and in child: handlecheckboxchanged or connectedcallback is not getting the changed value dynamically. Inshort, I am trying to learn to see the parent value when referred in child component gets the value dynamically on every time it is changed in the parent.

Comment: @SFDCLearner Correct. connectedCallback is only called when the component first connects to the DOM, and onchange won't be called unless the user manually clicks the child checkbox. If you want to see changes to the property, the appropriate ways would be either a renderedCallback or a getter/setter pair. Try this in the child: `#value; @api set isvaluechecked(value) { console.log(value); this.#value = value; } get isvaluechecked() { return this.#value; }` instead of `@api isvaluechecked = false`.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks a lot for the great knowledge!

Comment: By the way, @api are now no longer read-only right? except for objects? Though it is seen a good practice to not mutate the parent public property?

Comment: @prem22 The public properties themselves have been unprotected for a couple of years now. However, developers should treat them as readonly. Data binding can only occur from parent to child, and if the parent changes a bound value, the child will lose whatever data they assumed they had. This can make debugging more difficult than it needs to be, especially in large projects.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks a lot. The last approach worked

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you very much for the explanation!